# How Do I Input Todays Date Into a List?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, date-time

looking to add todays date into sharepoint list so that I can run multiple expiry timelines off other cells.
Have looked online and tried the work arounds but can't able to get any working code.

I have tried multiple ways like

- Created text column as Today.
- Added another calculated column and put [today] in the calculated field.

If any one have idea about this please let me know

Many thanks.

Jason.

Comment: try calculated column with Now() as formula

Comment: thankyou very much this works well :) now the challenge I have is the difference between two dates works when I use the now() column and a date that's in the past but it gives me a #NUM! error for any date in the future. Any ideas????

Comment: Can you tell me what formula you have written for calculating difference.  I have used following formula and it works : =[Date Time]-Calc where [Date Time] is column of type Date& Time , calc is caluated column with formula Now(). Also return type for above formula is set as "Number"

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get your point and also searched on the web for the same.

Please go through this thread [Column calculated value to get the current date time?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30050/column-calculated-value-to-get-the-current-date-time) and let me know if it help you.

Thanks

Comment: thankyou this has resolved the challenge of knowing when dates are within a window.

Comment: if it helped you then please mark the answer as accepted so that it can help others